# Can we stay invertible while approximating linear maps in Sobolev spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded domain with a smooth boundary. Fix $1<p<n$.

Let $A \in W^{1,p}(\Omega;\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \cap C(\Omega;\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with $\det A > 0$ a.e.

> Do there exist $u_n \in C^{\infty}\big(\Omega,\text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n)\big)$ such that $u_n \to A$ in $W^{1,p}_{loc}$?
>
> I am also interested in a weaker  result: Are there $u_n \in C^{\infty}\big(\Omega,\text{End}( \mathbb{R}^n)\big)$, such that $u_n(x) \in \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a.e. **and**
> $u_n \to  A$ in $W^{1,p}_{loc}$?

I don't really need the $u_n$ to be defined on all $\Omega$. It suffices that for **every** arbitrarily small ball in $\Omega$, there would be a neighbourhood where such a sequence $u_n$ would be defined.

The problem is that *it is not always true* that $A_x \in \text{GL}( \mathbb{R}^n)$ for *every* $x \in \Omega$. The rank can fall on a subset of measure zero.

**If we knew $A(x) \in \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n)$  everywhere then the answer would be positive.** This follows from the facts that "being invertible" is an open condition, and that continuous Sobolev maps can be *approximated uniformly* by smooth maps over compact subsets.

---

In more detail, let $K \subseteq \Omega$ be compact. Since we assumed $A \in C\big(\Omega, \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n) \big)$, the map $\psi:x \to A_x$, considered as a map $K \to \text{GL}( \mathbb{R}^n)$, is continuous. Thus $\psi(K) $ is compact and $\text{dist}\big(\psi(K),\partial \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n)\big)>0$.

Now consider each component of $\psi(x)=A_x \in \text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n) $. We can approximate  each component of $\psi$ using mollification on an open subset of $\Omega$ containing $K$. Since each component is a continuous function, the mollifications *converge uniformly* on $K$. This implies that from a certain point in the mollified sequence, $\text{dist}(u_n,A)<\text{dist}\big(\psi(K),\partial \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^n)\big)$, so the $u_n$ are invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will recycle the answer I've been writing into some words of explanation on Alex Gavrilov's example, which is more simple and elegant. We can focus on the first column $p_n$ of an approximating sequence $u_n:=[p_n,q_n]$ of $A(x,y):=\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{bmatrix}$. If $p_n\in C^0\cap W^{1,1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ converges in $W^{1,1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$, then for at least one $r_0>0$ (actually, for a.e. $r>0$) the sequence restricted to the boundary, $p_{n|\partial B(0,r_0)}$ is in $W^{1,1}(\partial B(0,r_0))$ and converges there, therefore also uniformly. Then for some $n_0$, $$\|p_{n_0|\partial B(0,r_0)}-{\operatorname{id}_{\partial B(0,r_0)}}\|_{\infty,\partial B(0,r_0) }<r_0$$  that implies that $ p_{n_0|B(0,r_0)} $ has degree $1$ and $p_n(x,y)$ vanishes in some $(x_0,y_0)\in B(0,r_0)$, so that $u_{n_0}(x_0,y_0)$ is not invertible.

For the weaker version, it is sufficient to approximate $A$ in $W^{1,p}_{loc}$ with a sequence of  polynomial maps $u_n$, since the polynomial $\det(u_n)$ is automatically non-vanishing a.e. as soon as it is not identically zero (which of course is eventually true,  since $\det(u_n(x_0))\to\det(A(x_0))>0$ holds at some point $x_0)$ )

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I hope you will be willing to clarify two points for me: (1) Regarding your last point, how do we rule out the possibility $\det(u_n)=0$ a.e. in general? It is not clear to me that the given assumptions $\det A > 0$ a.e. and $x \to A_x$ is continuous imply the existence of a compact subset (locally around every point) where $\det A \neq 0$. This holds in the example considered above. (2) Can you give me any reference for the phenomena that "Sobolev convergence" passes to the boundary? (I am referring to the restrictions $p_{n|\partial B(0,r_0)}$). Thanks again.

Comment: On a second thought, I also don't see how can you approximate $A$ with polynomials in $W^{1,p}$. (You can certainly approximate $A$ uniformly, and in particular in $L^p$, but how do you make sure the derivatives of the polynomials approximate the derivatives of $A$?)

Comment: I added a rmk for (1). The fact (2) about traces comes from the embedding $W^{1,1}(I\times J)$ in the Bochner space $L^1(I, W^{1,1}(J))$ which is essentially Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: On the last point: you can first approximate in $W^{1,p}_{loc}$ by a map in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which can be approximated $C^\infty_{loc}$  by polynomials. (Alternatively, one can do the argument of the last point with real analytic maps as well, instead of polynomial maps. To approximate a $W^{1,p}_{loc}$ function with a real analytic function, multiply   by a cut-off function, then mollify  by the Weierstrass kernel).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case $n=2$,

\begin{equation*}
A(x,y)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & -y \\
y & x 
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}

This function is not just in a Sobolev space, it is analytic. Obviously $\det A>0$ a.e, that is, except the origin. But you cannot approximate it by invertible matrices very well due to topological obstacles. (Not in $W^{1,p}$, at least.)

Your second question is completely different. I presume that the answer to it is positive (although I did not think about the details). You simply approximate $A$ by a smooth $u_n$ *somehow*, and if $\det u_n=0$ on a set of positive measure,  then you  tweak $u_n$ a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on these "topological obstructions"? (Why approximation by invertible matrices in $W^{1,p}$ is not possible?)

Comment: Because this is the operator of multiplication by $x+iy$, and it is not possible to approximate $f(z)=z$ near the origin by a function which does not vanish. (This is not exactly the same thing, but the conclusion is the same.)