# Can we approximate a vector field on the plane with non-vanishing vector fields in $W^{1,2}$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, singularity-theory

Let $V$ be a compactly-supported vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, whose zeros inside some open neighbourhood of the closed unit disk $\mathbb{D}^2$ are isolated.

> Does there exist a sequence of vector fields $V_n \in C^\infty \cap W^{1,2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $V_n \to V$ in $W^{1,2}$ and the $V_n$ do not vanish on  $\mathbb{D}^2$?

If we replace the $W^{1,2}$ convergence with $L^2$ convergence, than the answer [is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3439203/104576). The idea is to push the zeroes out of the disk by composing $V$ with a diffeomorphism which affects a region of very small measure.

Comment: The strongest convergence you want must be strictly weaker of the uniform convergence, because if $V_n\to V$ uniformly on $\overline{\mathbb{D}^2}$, and  $V$ has non-zero topological degree in $\mathbb{D}^2$ wrto $0$,  the same holds eventually for the $V_n$, and they will vanish as well. But $W^{2,2}(\mathbb{D}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is continuously embedded in $C^0(\mathbb{D}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$:  this convergence is too strong.

Comment: Minor side comment: compact support and isolated zeros are not compatible. Perhaps you meant that it only has isolated zeros on $\mathbb{D}^2$?

Comment: No, the topological degree is well defined and continuous in $C^0$ situations. There are also extensions of the degree theory in different settings, not included in $C^0$, like VMO mappings: in that topology the degree is also locally constant, but maybe it is not a problem for you, because a nonzero degree of $f$ on $U$ wrto $p$  does not imply that $f(x)=p$ has a solution $x\in U$, like for the classical case (i.e. a continuous $f:\overline U\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded open set, $p\notin f(\partial U)$)

Comment: Deleted my answer below because Pietro's comment made me doubt an essential part of my reasoning. For convenience, however, a survey of the VMO degree theory (which would apply in your case because $W^{1,2}$ embeds in $VMO$ in two dimensions) can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4467-9_3) (Brezis, "New questions related to the topological degree".)

Comment: Willie: Actually I think yours was a useful answer. Since Asaf's functions $V_n$ are assumed continuous, I'm not sure if my objection applies to your objection to his conjecture

Comment: @PietroMajer: I completely forgot about the $C^\infty$ part. Ok, I will undelete.

Comment: I think this was already answered by Pietro Majer's answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/307832/112284. Set $p_n$ there to $V_n$ here. (And apply a cutoff function i.e. multiply the counterexample $p_n$ by a $C^\infty$ function that is $1$ on a neighborhood of $\mathbb D^2,$ and restrict $r_0$ to $(0,1).$)

Comment: @Dap You are absolutely right...I didn't notice that Pietro's answer for my old question applies to this case as well. Thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from the topological index idea: let $C$ be a circle around one of the isolated zeros, and let $D$ be a disk containing $C$. By the trace theorem, your vector fields in $W^{1,2}(D)$ restricts to vector fields $W^{1/2,2}(C)$ on the circle. Since they do not vanish, you can regard them as vector fields $W^{1/2,2}(C, \mathbb{S}^1)$. (If there's any problem with my argument, it would be this step, passing from an $\mathbb{R}^2$ valued function to $\mathbb{S}^1$ valued one.)

The $W^{1/2,2}(C,\mathbb{S}^1)$ functions are continuously embedded in $VMO(C,\mathbb{S}^1)$ since $C$ is one dimensional, and one can use the $VMO$-degree theory (originally due to Boutet de Monvel and Gabber, and extended by Brezis and Nirenberg, see [this survey by Brezis](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4467-9_3)). The upshot is that for continuous functions the VMO degree coincides with the the usual topological degree, and the $VMO$-degree is continuous under $VMO$-convergence. So I think [Pietro's argument against the $W^{2,2}$ case using degree theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346238/can-we-approximate-a-vector-field-on-the-plane-with-non-vanishing-vector-fields#comment866546_346238) should carry over also, telling you that you shouldn't be able to do your approximation.

To be more precise: the chain of arguments should go something like: since your $V_n$ are in $C^\infty$ and has no zeros, their corresponding topological degree would be zero, measured either in $VMO$ or classically; but $V_n$ converges to $V$ in $VMO$ (by argument above), and this means that $V$ has to also have degree zero, a contradiction.